# Has Galactus ever been satiated?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, galactus

As the "devourer of worlds", Galactus hunger is LEGENDARY.  Hell, even after feasting on the life energy of a planet, he's STILL been hungry. Considering his power is at its height when fully fed, this could be a problem were he to go without for too long. So I was wondering:

Has there ever been a time Galactus was "fully satisfied" by a meal, and if so... does anyone have any scans or proof for how long it lasted?

Also...

On average, how often does Galactus HAVE to eat planets?

Comment: I remember watching this in an Animated series as well.. but there, Galactus is trapped in the negative zone by the Avegers ans Fantastic-4 where he would never have the need to be fed again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's happened (briefly) on at least one occasion in *[The Silver Surfer – The Ultimate Cosmic Experience](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2125032)* (1978).

Galactus had eaten several worlds in quick succession and was happy to take a breather. Suffice to say, it doesn't last long and he's back to his old ways before the end of the serial.

[image]

And who, of course, could forget the time (in [*Marvel Team Ups #137*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Team-Up_Vol_1_137)) that a superpowered Aunt May, working as Galactus' new herald fed him a gigantic, planet-sized Twinkle Bar in order to get him to leave Earth alone.

[image]

He was so full that he needed a glass of milk to settle his stomach afterwards.

[image]

Comment: Dude.... this was freaking awesome! I'd forgotten aunt May had been the **Golden Oldie** some year back. But this whole issue was little more than an extended Hostess commercial!

Comment: "Exiled from his home world for excessive baking practices, Dough Boy has roamed the universe creating planets called Twinkle Worlds in his wake." - Now there's a superhero origin story.

Comment: @OrangeDog - There is no story *so colossally stupid* or *bizarrely outlandish* that it hasn't been seen ***repeatedly*** in DC + Marvel comics